# C# string.ALL<> using contain to search a string - htmlagility

Tags: c#, string, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to **scrape** HTML file using htmlagility pack. I realize this is not issue with agility pack but related to understanding string manipulation , as per example code below, i'm expecting "not found" but it is returning as Found. It appears like searching as char instead of string. If I put XYZ in str1, result is not found. Can someone help me to how to get the desire result.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str1 = "PBS" ;
        string str2 = "JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV DEC ";

        if ( str1.All(x=> str2.Contains(x))  )
        {
            MessageBox.Show(str2);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Not Found");
        }

    }
```

My actual coding as below and i'm also getting html node that I don't want.

```
string monthValues = " JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN JUL AUG OCT NOV DEC ";
var header = ROWS[rowCount + 1].Descendants("TH").Where(node => node.InnerHtml.ToString().Substring(0,2).All(x => monthValues.Contains(x))).ToList();
```

and html as follow. I'm also getting "TH" node which has "PBS"

```
<tr>
<th class="l t colhd" rowspan="11"> 9494Q     </th>
<th class="l t colhd" rowspan="3">PBS </th>
<th class="l t colhd">FEB2021</th>
</tr>
```

Appreciate your help.

Regards

Comment: What is your actual goal here?  You want to find all <TH> tags that contain one of the month values?

Comment: Yes. but that is the goal to have TH tag with month value . And also curious how can i fix the syntax above to work in the way that searching string instead of searching by character.

Answer (score 1):

The code is looking for each individual character from str1 within str2. Hence the letters P B and S all appear in str2. X Y and Z do not.

I think you simply want

```
if (str2.Contains(str1))
```

Comment: Thank you. but if I reverse around to use this like if (str2.Contains(str1) ), i need to loop through each TH. i thought there would be better way to shorten it and also want to know if possible to make str1.All(x=> str2.Contains(x)) work in the way that i want.